# AS3 how to check if sound object is buffering http sound stream

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, buffer

was wondering how i can check if sound object is buffering a http audio stream in as3? like shoutcast/icecast etc. i searched but nothing came to me that can do this job. so any hint or idea will be appreciated. i found isbuffering but the problem that isbuffering only stop when whole sound is loaded and this will never happen in a streamed audio.

Thanks alot

Comment: I think you answered your own question: a streamed audio is always buffering, because the download will never finish.

Comment: my intention was a way to make a status show when audio buffer is empty and audio cant play & disappear when canplay. i am sure there is a way but donno where to begin

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the "progress" event or check changing of the "bytesLoaded" property.

Comment: sound.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, function(event:ProgressEvent):void {
// A new run of the indicator. If you don't restart the playback indicator it will be stopped
});

Comment: Or (for "bytesLoaded" property):
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(event:TimerEvent):void {
 // Check sound.bytesLoaded. If it is 0 or isn't changed then stream is waiting or stopped
});